# Putting in accented character in gnuplot xlabel

Tags: character-encoding, gnuplot, symbols

I'm running gnuplot Version 5.0 patchlevel 5, on MacOSX.

My gnuplot MWE is:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 4.5,3.5 enhanced color font 'Times-Roman,25' linewidth 2
set out "plot.eps"

set xlabel "~{/Symbol l}{.8\^}_s"
set ylabel "Ylabel" offset 1.5
plot [-10:10] sin(x)
```

However I get the error

```
     warning: enhanced text parser - spurious }
     warning: enhanced text parser - spurious }
```

This is the problem with the line

```
set xlabel "~{/Symbol l}{.8\^}_s"
```

If I write this, it works fine:

```
set xlabel "~{/Symbol l}{.8-}_s"
```

However I want to use this accent **^** on top of the lambda symbol. How to do it?

Comment: Add extra backslash: `\\^`

Comment: It works. @MichaelO. maybe you can put this as an answer